# Log message in Application insight from postman

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

using the below azure restapi, i have created an applicationinsight from postman.
PUT [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/{resourceName}?api-version=2015-05-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/%7BresourceName%7D?api-version=2015-05-01)

I want to log a simple message from postman.
but i dont find any specific property to assign logs.
Can anyone help me on this.?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/{resourceName}?api-version=2015-05-01
```

Above **RESTAPI** call is used to create or update the application Insights properties like location, application type, and [others in MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#request-body).

As per MSDOC, currently there is **no RESTAPI call to add Metrics to Application Insights**. As we currently we have **RESTAPI calls to query the metrics** these are available in [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/).

#### The REST API Calls to get metrics

[image]